# Submitting binary to Apple with 3rd party libraries

Tags: ios, binary, zip, sharekit

I made an app using ShareKit ... When I want to zip the binary to submit it to Apple, I also see two libraries in the folder.

Should I zip them all together (.ipa and the two libraries) or should I submit just the .ipa?

It seems like both work with the Application Loader ...

And the .ipa file contains one of them but not both. The app works fine on a device.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I actually had no idea I could do it ... always did it with the Application Loader. Just rejected the uploaded zip and I am doing it with the Organizer.  Thanks for the quick reply!!!

Comment: I submitted my comment as an answer since it solved your issue! (On this site whenever an answer helps you up-vote and accept it! :P)

Answer (score 1):

Use Xcode 4's archive feature and submit via Organizer that way you are not dealing with messy zips and other folders. That should solve your issue!